# dividing a string into an array in C using strtok

Tags: c, string, strtok

I am making a small program where a user types a command like "print 1 2" or "open file1" and in order to process what the user wants to do I'm trying to break up the user input at every space using `strtok`. My problem is that for the following code:

```
void tokenize(char string[100],char tokenized[10][MAX_CHARS]){
    char delims[] = " ";        /*Delimitere is a space so tokenize when a space occurs*/
    char *result = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    result=strtok(string,delims);   /*Tokenize the string*/
    while(result!=NULL && count<10){
        tokenized[count++][MAX_CHARS] = result;  /* This is where I get the error */
        result= strtok(NULL,delims);
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
stringapi.c: In function ‘tokenize’:
stringapi.c:33:33: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

I have been trying to solve this problem for awhile with no luck.
I tried `tokenized[count++] = result;` but that gives me the following error:

```
stringapi.c:33:22: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[80]’ from type ‘char *’
```

My end goal is that if user types "open newfile.txt" I want to have an array where
`array[0]` is open and `array[1]` is newfile.txt which then I can process accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

The following line:

```
tokenized[count++] = result;
```

tries to assign to an array of chars. [You can't do that](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/arrayassign.html), you have to use [`strncpy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strncpy.html):

```
strncpy(tokenized[count++], result, MAX_CHARS);
```

Finally, I would recommend that you prefer [`strtok_r()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strtok.html) to `strtok()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `strcpy` (or better `strncpy`) to copy strings. Otherwise you are just assigning a pointer into an array.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up two approaches. One approach is where you copy everything from the input string into different locations for the parsed version. One approach is where the parsed version is just a bunch of pointers into the memory that held the original input string memory. That `tokenized[...] = result` line is trying to do the second approach; the data structures you're using are indicative of the first approach.

If you want to use the first approach, do a strncpy instead of just assigning to tokenized. If you want to use the second approach, change tokenized into an array of char*.

I would recommend the first approach, for what it's worth.